# How to run tests from go project root folder?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am working through the text, "Writing an Interpreter in Go" by Thorsten Ball in order to learn about the language.

Project Directory looks like this:

```
Interpreter/
|---code/
|   |---token/
|   |   |---token.go
|   |   |---go.mod
|   |---lexer/
|       |---lexer_test.go
|       |---go.mod
|---go.mod
```

I created the *go.mod* files in this manner

```
>go mod init monkey
>cd token
>go mod init token
>cd ../lexer
>go mod init lexer
```

I added this line to the *go.mod* file in the lexer module

```
replace monkey/token => ../token
```

On running `go test` from inside the lexer folder, I get the expected output as mentioned in the book, but I realize this is not an indicator of the project being setup properly.

```
>go test
# lexer [lexer.test]
./lexer_test.go:26:7: undefined: New
FAIL    lexer [build failed]
```

But on running the tests as mentioned in the book, i.e. from the root folder *code* in the following manner:

```
go test ./lexer
```

go is unable to resolve the lexer package and I get the following error

```
main module (monkey) does not contain package monkey/lexer
```

Is there something that needed to be added to the *go.mod* file in the root folder that fixes this?

Comment: You should have one go.mod per project, not one per every package. Then to test everything from the root you can do `go test ./...`.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. I deleted the mod files in the subdirectories and get the expected output. Also, is `go mod init monkey` at the root directory the correct way to create the go.mod? Do I need to add anything else to it?

Comment: In general you should supply a module "path" to `go mod init` instead of just the name. *"A module path should describe both what the module does and where to find it. Typically, a module path consists of a repository root path, a directory within the repository (usually empty), and a major version suffix (only for major version 2 or higher)."* For example `go mod init github.com/kchak/monkey`. Read more here: https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-path. -- Note that this is not a requirement and it is ultimately up to you, if you want to use just `monkey` that should be ok.

Comment: Note that the module path becomes the prefix of the import paths of the packages inside the module. So, for example, if the `lexer` package wants to import the `token` package then it must specify the import path as `import "github.com/kchak/monkey/code/token"`.

Comment: A module is a set of packages versioned together.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was

```
$ cd 01/src/monkey
$ go mod init monkey
$ go test ./lexer
```

Answer (score -1):

As @mkopriva notes, the simple solution is to delete the `go.mod` files from the `token` and `lexer` directories.

In general, a Go project should have a single `go.mod` file at the project root: each `go.mod` file indicates a *self-contained* module.